# using tf.keras.utils.get_file() for google drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use tf.keras.utils.get_file("URL from google drive")
When I use URL which has less than 33MB it works well
However, when I try to download file more than 33MB it's not working well.

How can I solve this problem?

```
_URL = 'URL FROM GOOGLE DRIVE'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file("file_name.zip", origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'art_filename')
```

I am following https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification
this for my practice, and I am trying to use my own data for the practice.
In this example, it uses URL as "storage.googleapi.com..." and has large amount of data.

I want to use this code for downloading large data from google drive. 
Is there anyway to solve this problem?

I also tried google mounting but since I want to access the folders and files, 
I am not used to do with google mounting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Files that are above a certain size pop-up with a notification from Drive letting you know that it cannot be scanned for viruses which needs to be accepted before the file can download. By appending "&confirm=t" to the end of the download URL, you can bypass that message and download your files.